# CRA + react-intl crashing when id is unknown

Tags: reactjs, react-intl

I am using create-react-app and react-intl and I am having the issue that I am fetching data from an API and I want this data to be translated into several languages `<FormattedMessage {...messages['fetched-id']} />`component from react.intl
Because I can't 100% rely on the API output it can happen that some id's returned by the API are not defined in my translation files. What happens in the end is that react-intl crashes because of an unknown id `(Error: [@formatjs/intl] An` id `must be provided to format a message)`

Now I wanted to know if there is a way with CRA that I can prevent the react-intl lib from crashing and to render a fallback in this case (which can be the id that has been passed - in the same manner like react-i18next does it).

I saw in other posts that it's recommended to use the `babel-plugin-formatjs` together with craco to fix this issue (https://github.com/formatjs/formatjs/issues/1901). Unfortunately this didn't work for me.

Example:

I am using:

```
defineMessages({
  guitar: {
    id: 'app.components.Text.guitar',
    defaultMessage: 'Guitar',
  }
})
```

and in my en.json file I have my english translations :

```
"app.components.Text.guitar": "Guitar",
```

calling `<FormattedMessage {...messages['<instrument-name>']} />`

and now I am fetching instruments from the server and I want to translation them into several languages. If now for example the server returns an instrument name that is not defined via `defineMessages` or in the `en.json` file then it will complain that a id must be provided. And I am wondering if in that case I can prevent it to crash and just render the  that was passed instead? Hope this was somehow understandable

Comment: Are you not able to check for the `id` property before trying to render it?

Answer (score 0):

Hopefully I'm not misunderstanding what you say you are receiving from your server. You can check if the message object has an `id` property first, then either spread it in, or some fallback string object.

```
<FormattedMessage
  {...(messages[idFromServer]?.id ? messages[idFromServer] : messages.fallback)}
/>
```

Comment: Thanks for replying. I updated my question to make it more clear what I was talking about

Comment: @SebastianG I saw your edits, but my perceived understanding of your question remains unchanged. Have you tried my solution, or variation of it, to first check if the translation key actually returns a string object with an `id` property?